# horizontal scroll not working in ionic application build through xcode for ios mobile app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic4

Have created a hybrid app using ionic framework. I have used a div and defined a table under this div. styling of div is as follows:
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;

Size of table is such that it should add scroll to the div. When I build for android, scroll is working fine, but when I build for IOS, scroll is visible but not working. I am not able to scroll the div to view all the columns of the table. Please help.

No Error message, just horizontal scroll not working

Comment: Which iOS device are you using?

Comment: i have checked this on simulator (multiple targets - 5,5s, 6, 7) and also on mobile device iPhone 7